# formidable:- Hide short code closing bracket on page

Tags: wordpress, formidable

I am using formidable plugin here i have created one page and using bellow short code on page to display form entry using view id 438.

```
[display-frm-data id=438 user_id=[176 show=id]]
```

my problem is that in the end of view's entries it's showing closing bracket of short code like this "]"

you can see this in bellow snippet highlighted in red circile .

[image: bracket]

so how can i remove it.as i have used this short code form authorized source from [https://formidablepro.com/knowledgebase](https://formidablepro.com/knowledgebase/advanced-displays/)

Comment: sure it shouldn't be just:
[display-frm-data id=438 user_id=176 show=id]

Comment: @flauntster  if use this page says entry not found.

Comment: @flauntster check this link for short code details https://formidablepro.com/knowledgebase/advanced-displays/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i search from the web but didn't got the way so i have used my way added one `div` before of `]` closing bracket of short code and settled `div` style property `visibility:hidden;` like a bellow snippet code.

I don't know how much is right or wrong but it temporary work for me.

```
[display-frm-data id=438 user_id=[176 show=id]<div style="visibility: hidden;">]</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That documentation is confusing. It doesn't actually mean to include a second set of brackets. It's simply saying that anything between the second set of brackets is a placeholder for what you should actually place there.

In fact, including additional brackets within a shortcode is [illegal according to the WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Square_Brackets).

The correct form of the shortcode is:

```
[display-frm-data id=438 user_id=176 show=id]
```

Comment: if use this page says entry not found

Comment: That means there is no user with `id=176`

Comment: but it work with [display-frm-data id=438 user_id=[176 show=id]] and shows all entry created by current user but just "]" bracket issue